# Redirect warning about remote host identification change

Tags: linux, redirect

When I am checking a remote host is active or not by ssh, an warning message shown as below always pops up on the screen. Though it is a normal progress in my program but it really affect the user experience by seeing it on the screen. Is there any way to hide it or redirect it to other files?

Warning message:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
```

Comment: Unsure whether it would be more on topic on Server Fault. Anyway an important information is missing here: how do you connect to the remote host? ssh?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes, by ssh. It is updated to the question statement.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignoring it, investigate why the host key of the remote host has changed. If it's for a legitimate reason (another machine got the old IP address (and you actually want to connect to the new machine), or the host keys were re-generated for some reason), then delete the corresponding line from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.